# How to publish the angularjs project from Webstorm

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

There is a lot out there on how WebStorm is great for editing angular, and their built-in template is quite good; however, i can't find anything on what do i do when i'm happy with the app.

Say i create the default template, how can i get a nice folder structure for this app so that i can ftp it to a remote server?

Better yet, is it possible to 'compile' (package) my entire angular dependancies and modules into one .js file and then for example have an index.html just reference that somehow?

Comment: use gulp or grunt to compile builds. The IDE itself is not a build tool but has support for them. Also have built in deployment ftp with lots of options if you haven't found that already

Comment: Yeoman has a great [Angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) generator. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKiaLSJW5xI) for more details

Comment: @charlietfl any links you can provide? i keep reading about these two but when you go their pages they say 'this is a tool for running tasks'. Doesn't say it's a tool for building projects.

Comment: @Freezystem read the readme on github - just like webstorm, elaborate 'how do i get started' and nothing on 'i finished my app, how do i release it?'

Comment: lots of tutorials on using both. Those tasks are automation tasks for doing lots and lots of different things including compiling your `package`

Answer (score 0):

you can inspire yourself from this [excellent Yeoman generator](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular).

I'm currently using it and when I'm done coding and testing with `gulp serve` I just release my app by compiling all my source code with the `gulp build` command.

Architecture is as follow and I personally found that's a really good one :

```
├──  src/
│   ├──  app/
│   │   ├──  components/
│   │   │   └──  navbar/
│   │   │   │   ├──  navbar.controller.js
│   │   │   │   └──  navbar.html
│   │   ├──  main/
│   │   │   ├──  main.controller.js
│   │   │   ├──  main.controller.spec.js
│   │   │   └──  main.html
│   │   └──  index.js
│   │   └──  index.(css|less|scss)
│   │   └──  vendor.(css|less|scss)
│   ├──  assets/
│   │   └──  images/
│   ├──  404.html
│   ├──  favico.ico
│   └──  index.html
├──  gulp/
├──  e2e/
├──  bower_components/
├──  nodes_modules/
├──  .bowerrc
├──  .editorconfig
├──  .gitignore
├──  .jshintrc
├──  bower.json
├──  gulpfile.js
├──  karma.conf.js
├──  package.json
├──  protractor.conf.js
```

Once you've run `gulp build` all your JS files are compiled to one unique `index.js` file and so do your style files. All vendor scripts included by bower are also compiled to one and stored in `vendor.js` file in your dist directory.

Comment: I had an already ready to go project that I wanted to package up. I did all the steps (made the project gulpy) then when all way done as instructed in the link you provided I ran, gulp serve, gulp build. I do not see a index.js file anywhere. Where should I be looking?